# ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemStringFormat not set correctly

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am using a `ComboBox` displaying floats (in `Choices`) as percent values:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemStringFormat="P0"
    IsEditable="True"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject.PrePlanningStatus,  Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=P0}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" />
```

The choices are correctly displayed with the percent symbol. However, the `SelectedItem` is displayed as normal float value without a percent symbol (thus with wrong format).

`ItemTemplate` has the same behaviour. It seems that the `ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemStringFormat` property is not set correctly as this value is null at runtime. However this property is `readonly`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DataTemplate` to specify how items are displayed in a universal way:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject.CavernDetails.PrePlanningStatus,  Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=P0}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank your for your help. However, setting an ItemTemplate has the same behaviour. The selected item is displayed without any format. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that using a ComboBox without `IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"` settings the selected item is displayed within the correct format. For me these settings are also fine.